# firefox profile with webdriver

Tags: firefox, webdriver, profile

I want to create a custom firefox profile on my remote machine (with image load disabled, tab options, etc) 
When my tests start, I want to use that profiles but I have no idea why it doesn't work. 
Basically, I have all my tests on my main machine and run them on a remote machine
I tried something like this:

```
 ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();
 FirefoxProfile profile = allProfiles.getProfile("TestProfile");
 caps.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE,profile);
```

But, the profile that starts on my remote machine is different ( guess it starts a new one called anonymous159735848120713345webdriver-profile)

Any suggestion?

Comment: Does 'TestProfile' exist?

Comment: Yes, it exists! But the "anonymous..." profile is created and used every time.I tried to remove it but no way

Answer (score 0):

If you are using selenium grid start your firefox node adding the parameter `-Dwebdriver.firefox.profile=TestProfile`

Comment: great,  got it :-). But, the option "open new windows in a new tab instead" is still unchecked , even i checked it in my profile!? I really need to have that option checked. Any idea?

Comment: I guess we can't, Check this- [link](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3380)

Comment: hi! Shame, but the info is old (Apr 16, 2012) , maybe has been implemented :-)